# Caché Git - CSP folder don't import if it does not exist in local directory

Tags: git, version-control, intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

I have a versioned CSP folder on my CSP application , when I create a new local environment where that folder does not exist yet in the CSP application, the version control it does not create or import any of your files or subfolders.

Comment: So what's your question then?

Comment: The question is why?